# How to get data from the database from Xcode(swift)

Tags: ios, mysql, json, xcode

I have a question about the get data from MySQL.
I can post the data to the database through the app and using the PHP. Moreover, I can get the data from the database through the JSON data and the webserver can show the data clearly too. However, in my Xcode, I cannot get the data so I suspect the code in the Xcode is incorrect.

This is the JSON data:

```
 <?php
        require_once("info.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

    $response = array();
    $posts = array();
    $result = $dbconnect->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $water = $row['water'];
            $posts[] = array('id' => $id, 'water'=>$water);

        }
        $response['data'] = $posts;

        $data = $response['data'];
        $water = $data[0]['water'];
        echo json_encode($water);


    }
?>
```

This is the Xcode:

```
 @objc func GetFromServer() {
        let nsUrl = URL(string: urlString)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: nsUrl!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject?]
                if let arrayData = jsonData["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    // Remove all previous data.
                    self.tableData.removeAll()
                    for data in arrayData {
                        self.tableData.append(data as! [String : String])
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        let water = "\(self.tableData[0]["water"]!)"
                        print("Data: \(water)")
                            serial.sendMessageToDevice("\(water)")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                // Error.
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Thanks for all the reply

Comment: You should use `Codable` rather than walking the structure. What output do you get from your app? Do you get any errors? Actually printing any errors would probably be a help

Comment: I can get the numbers from MySQL because I can show the number in my webserver and I don't have any error. The problem is I can get the data in JSON, but the data doesn't post to my Xcode, because the console in Xcode doesn't show anything.
Thank you for the reply.

Comment: But you don't print anything in the error case and you don't check the `error` parameter passed to your closure isn't `nil` and print that if it isn't, so it isn't surprising that there is nothing on the console

Comment: You are right, So I add the print("error") below the }catch{. And now it shows "error" in the console and I know the function cannot work. So why the do function cannot work? I cannot find the reason.

Comment: Don't `print("error")`, do `if let err = error { print(err) }` - the error will tell you what is going wrong

Comment: Is your URL using https?  If not you will need to disable ATS

Comment: My URL not using https, I try to disable it

Comment: I found that I disable the ATS already.